# Template alias and specialization

Tags: c++

Assuming we have

```
template<typename T> 
struct Foo
{
};

template<typename T> 
struct Bar
{
};

template< template<typename T> class C >
struct Pack
{
    template<typename T>
    using Container = C<T>;
};
```

Are `Foo` and `Pack<Foo>::Container` supposed to be treated as the same thing if we have a specialization for `Foo`? That is:

```
template< template<typename T> class C >
struct IsFoo : std::false_type
{
};

template<>
struct IsFoo<Foo> : std::true_type
{
};

static_assert( IsFoo<Foo>::value,                             "Only foos!" );
static_assert( IsFoo< Pack<Foo>::Container >::value,          "Only foos!" ); // ???
static_assert( IsFoo< Pack<Bar>::Container >::value == false, "Not a foo!" );
```

Is that second assertion correct? What is the expected behavior? Heck, is what I am trying to do even valid?

I tested it on three compilers and I got different results. It seems that for
MSVC and CLang, `Foo` and `Pack<Foo>::Container` are not the same thing, but [GCC disagrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/622df10803be63cd), which is cool, because that is exactly what I wanted.

So, who is right?

PS: I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology on the title, nor inside the body of my question. Suggestions and corrections are more than welcome.

Comment: I thought template specialization is for types or values. Here `Foo` is a template, neither a type nor a value. +1 for the question.

Comment: [CWG1286](http://wg21.link/cwg1286).

Comment: Modifying your example such that `IsFoo`'s template parameter is a typename rather than a template makes both MSVC and GCC have the same output as for GCC on your original example. (see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3052a75286f82e2).

Comment: But question is about *template template parameters*, your example is *exactly* same as what is currently in standard. (§14.4/1.7)

Comment: @user1593842 What is significance of "using Container = C<T>;" code line here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [14.5.7 Alias templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)
>
> 1 A template-declaration in which the declaration is an alias-declaration 
>      (Clause 7) declares the identifier to be a alias template. An alias 
>      template is a name for a family of types. The name of the alias 
>      template is a template-name.
>
> 2 When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias 
>      template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by 
>      substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters 
>      in the type-id of the alias template.

In your example `Foo` and `Pack<Foo>::Container` (no parameter list) are template-names that don't represent a type but only a template. For example `Foo<int>` and `Pack<Foo>::Container<int>` would be template-ids and would thus be equivalent.

To my knowledge the standard doesn't specify any equivalence relation between template-names, so MSVC and Clang are right to assume that only identical template-names are equivalent.

But you could still specialize or overload based on the template-id if that is sufficient for your specific use case. e.g.:

```
template< typename C >
struct IsFoo : std::false_type
{
};

template<class T>
struct IsFoo<Foo<T>> : std::true_type
{
};

static_assert( IsFoo<Foo<int>>::value,                             "Only foos!" );
static_assert( IsFoo< Pack<Foo>::Container<int> >::value,          "Only foos!" );
static_assert( IsFoo< Pack<Bar>::Container<int> >::value == false, "Not a foo!" );
```

or

```
template<class T>
void do_stuff(const T&) {}

template<class T>
void do_stuff(const Foo<T>&) {}
```